# Изменение записи в БД Active Record Yii2 GET SET запросы

Tags: yii2, activerecord, model

Здравствуйте, задача заключается в том, чтобы изменить запись в бд через форму. Начнем.

В БД есть столбец date: он содержит запись "2018-02-08 15:00:00".

Я хочу чтобы у меня была форма, где можно отдельно изменить дату и время:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код полей:

```
echo $form->field($planItem, 'StartDate')->widget(DatePicker::classname(),['name' => 'dp_2',
'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd']]);

echo $form->field($planItem, 'Starttime')->widget(TimePicker::classname(),
 ['pluginOptions' => ['showMeridian' => false, 'minuteStep' => 1]]);
```

Для этого я в модели создал приватные переменные и функции get set.
Код модели:

```
public function getStartdate()
{
    return $this->startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->date));
}


public function setStartdate($startdate)
{
    $this->startdate = trim($startdate);
}


public function getStarttime()
{
    return $this->starttime = date('H:i', strtotime($this->date));
}


public function setStarttime($starttime)
{
    $this->starttime = trim($starttime);
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что как бы мы не меняли данные, все равно возвращаются в перменные Starttime и Startdate старые переменные, те, что были в бд. ( т.е. в бд было "2018-02-08 15:00:00", я изменил на "2018-02-08 16:05:00", вернулось обратно "2018-02-08 15:00:00").

В модели так же присутствуют функция, которая собирает дату и время в одно целое:

```
public function createDate()
{
    $this->date = $this->Startdate . ' ' . $this->Starttime . ':00';
}
```

После чего я вызываю эту функцию в контроллере. Но опять же, значения не меняются.

Comment: В модели при этом у Вас есть правила валидации для полей `StartDate` и `Starttime`? Если нет, то логично что с формы не приходят нужные данные этих полей.

Comment: код контроллера очень надо сюда